# Count visible rows in html table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

How to count total visible rows in html table using javascript, I have a code below that filters table rows while typing, I would like to see the number count of visible rows displayed in an innerHTML whole typing automatically

i tried this line of code but i dont see any results in the innerHTML

`document.getElementById("statistic").innerHTML = tr[i].length;`

FULL CODE

```js
        function myFunction() {

            // Declare variables

                var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
                input = document.getElementById("myInput");
                filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                table = document.getElementById("MyTable");
                tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");


                // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
                for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1]; // change number to any other number to target column for table search
                    if (td) {
                        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                            tr[i].style.display = "";

                             document.getElementById("statistic").innerHTML = tr[i].length;


                        } else {
                            tr[i].style.display = "none";

                        }
                    }
        }
```

Comment: it doesnt count the visible ones when i filter, only the total of all visible/non visible rows
document.getElementById("statistic").innerHTML = table.rows.length;

Comment: Runnable example using your code. Second answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 function myFunction() {

            // Declare variables

     var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
     input = document.getElementById("myInput");
     filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
     table = document.getElementById("MyTable");
     tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");


     // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
     rowsFound = [];
     for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
         td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1]; // change number to any other number to target column for table search
         if (td) {
             txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
             if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
             tr[i].style.display = "";
             rowsFound.push(1)
          } else {
              tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
   }
}
document.getElementById("statistic").innerHTML = rowsFound.length;
}

myFunction()
```

```html
<input id="myInput" onInput="myFunction();">
<table id="MyTable">
<div id="statistic"></div>
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>A</td>
<td>A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>B</td>
<td>B</td>
<td>B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>B</td>
<td>B</td>
<td>B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>C</td>
<td>C</td>
<td>C</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?

```js
const
  txt2search   = document.querySelector('#txt-2-search')
, searchResult = document.querySelector('#search-result')
, btSearch     = document.querySelector('#bt-search')
, myTable      = document.querySelector('#my-table')
  ;
btSearch.onclick =()=>
  {
  let 
    counter = 0
  , txt     = txt2search.value.trim()
  , Regtxt  = new RegExp(txt, 'i')
    ;
  myTable.querySelectorAll('tr.noDisplay').forEach(tr => tr.classList.remove('noDisplay'));

  if (txt==='')
    {
    searchResult.textContent = 'nothing to search...';
    return;
    }
  for (let tr of myTable.tBodies[0].rows)
    {
    if (Regtxt.test(tr.innerText )) counter++;
    else                            tr.classList.add('noDisplay');
    } 
  searchResult.textContent = 
    (counter===0) ? 'no result' : `${counter} element(s) found`;
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
  margin      : 1rem;
  }
table {
  border-collapse  : separate;
  border-spacing   : 1px;
  background-color : lightslategrey;
  }
th { background: cadetblue;  padding: .3em .6em; }
td { background: whitesmoke; padding: .2em .5em; }
tr *:first-child { text-align: center; font-style: oblique; }
tr * { white-space: nowrap; }
.noDisplay { display: none; }

caption {
  text-align : left;
  padding    : .4rem;
  font-size  : 1.2rem;
  background : #a0dbdd;
  }
#search-result {
  float     : right;
  font-size : .9rem;
  }
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <caption> 
    Find :
    <input type="text" id="txt-2-search" placeholder="show rows with...?">
    <button id="bt-search"> show rows </button>
    <span id="search-result">.</span>
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Age</th><th>Date of Birth</th><th>Nationality</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>John</td><td>Smith</td><td>Pearse Street</td><td>45</td><td>01/10/1977</td><td>English</td></tr>
    <tr><td>11</td><td>Tim</td><td>Green</td><td>Rosedale Avenue</td><td>23</td><td>17/04/1999</td><td>American</td></tr>
    <tr><td>114</td><td>Tom</td><td>Deane</td><td>Greenwood Road</td><td>42</td><td>27/11/1980</td><td>English</td></tr>
    <tr><td>208</td><td>Anna</td><td>Green</td><td>Rosedale Avenue</td><td>23</td><td>11/06/1999</td><td>Scottish</td></tr>
    <tr><td>259</td><td>Rachel</td><td>Waters</td><td>Station Road</td><td>87</td><td>11/02/1936</td><td>Irish</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>George</td><td>Taylor</td><td>Beach Avenue</td><td>52</td><td>30/07/1971</td><td>South African</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>Neil</td><td>Smyth</td><td>Beach Road</td><td>6</td><td>15/12/2016</td><td>Australian</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>Sarah</td><td>Smyth</td><td>Beach Road</td><td>30</td><td>06/01/1993</td><td>Australian</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```